# Creating global Ninject kernel in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I want to access Ninject Kernel in **Application_BeginRequest()** method. So I set Ker nel in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

```
   public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        public IKernel Kernel
        {
            get { return (IKernel) HttpContext.Current.Items["Context"]; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Items["Context"] = value; }
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            .....

            Kernel = new StandardKernel();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
                         new NinjectDependencyResolver(Kernel);

            Debug.WriteLine("Application started with kernel: {0}", Kernel);
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Application begin request with kernel: {0}", Kernel);
        }
```

I start application but Kernel object is coming null in `Application_BeginRequest()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Items` are request specific. So they are recreated for each request. In order to be able to access the `Kernel` in a request, you need to set it on a per-request-basis in `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    private static Kernel globalKernel;

    public static IKernel Kernel
    {
        get { return (IKernel) HttpContext.Current.Items["Context"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["Context"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        .....

        globalKernel = new StandardKernel();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
                     new NinjectDependencyResolver(globalKernel);

        Debug.WriteLine("Application started with kernel: {0}", globalKernel);
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        // This adds the Kernel to the items collection that is specific to the request
        Kernel = globalKernel;
        Debug.WriteLine("Application begin request with kernel: {0}", Kernel);
    }
```